# Have to configure my batch script to run on windows every day at 8 AM

Tags: batch-file, window, scheduler

I have batch script , that will take update of code base and do a build all the related projects.I want to run this script automatically without running manually every day at 8AM.

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file you wish to run and place it under a folder where you have enough permission. For example under C drive.
Click on Start and under search, type in Task and click open Task Scheduler.
Select Create Basic Task from the Action pane on the right of the window.
Under Create Basic Task, type in the name you like and click Next.
From the Trigger select the option you like and click Next. Select Date and Time.
Now click on Browser and select the batch file you like to run.
Finally, click on Finish to create the Task.
Now that you have created a Task, you have to make sure it runs with the highest privilege. Since you have UAC settings you have to make sure that when you run the file it should not fail if it does not bypass the UAC settings.
So click on Task Scheduler Library.
Then double click on the Task you just created.
Click on Run with Highest privilege then click OK.